# Lambda, Where com subconsulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Preciso de uma consulta assim no lambda

```
    SELECT  ClienteId  --Aqui eu tenho varios campos do Cliente e estagioprocesso
    FROM    Cliente
    WHERE   ((SELECT  TOP (1) EP
                             FROM  estagioprocesso 
                             WHERE     (estagioprocesso.ClienteID = Cliente.ClienteId)
                             ORDER BY estagioprocesso.ID DESC)= 2)
```

**Ou seja, verifico na tabela EtapaProcess qual é o último EP desse cliente (order by ID DESC) pego apenas 1 (top 1) e verifico esse EP se for igual ao número que quero retorno.**

quero trazer todas as etapas dos clientes que a etapa mais recente tem o EP = id (2).

Tentei:

```
int id = 2;
var EP = db.EtapaProcess
       .Include(t => t.Cliente)
       .OrderByDescending(t => t.EP).Take(1).Where(x => x.EP == id)
       .ToList();
```

Mas não dá certo. Ex: Existem 188 registros que já passaram pelo EP=2, porém que estão com EP=2 somente 5 registros e com a consulta acima me retorna 0

Comment: Não seria só trocar .ToList(); para .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Creio que não a consulta até processa, porém retorna 0, enquanto que o padrão que eu queria retornaria 5 registros.
Olhando a consulta que ele Gera pelo Diagnostic Tools é uma consulta complexa e nada haver..

Comment: Tem certeza  que tem x.EP == id? Tenta fazer a busca sem o INCLUDE

Comment: na verdade x.EP ==id (no caso id=2) tem 188 registros, porém quero os clientes que o último ep seja o ID=2 ai só teria 5..

Comment: Faça assim var EP = db.EtapaProcess.Take(1).Where(x => x.EP == id)
       .ToList();

Comment: Está quase... mas devo pegar o último (1) id do cliente.. ou seja, vejo lá na tabela mando ordenar pelo autonumeravel order by desc retorno somente 1 e ai verifico qual é esse EP se for o 2 no caso recupero as informações... vou tentar melhorar minha dúvida para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Certo, tenta postar o que voce quer com SQL PURO

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35250/discussion-between-paulohdsousa-and-dorathoto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pelo o que entendi, você quer trazer todas as etapas dos clientes que a etapa mais recente tem o EP = id (2).

Neste caso, você terá de agrupar por cliente, para então fazer a comparação.

```
var epClientes = db.EtapaProcess
    .Include(etapa => etapa.Cliente)
    .GroupBy(etapa => etapa.ClienteID)
    .Where(grupo => grupo
        .OrderByDescending(etapa => etapa.ID)
        .Select(etapa => etapa.EP)
        .FirstOfDefault() == 2);

var EP = new List<EtapaProcess>();
foreach (var epCliente in epClientes)
{
    EP.AddRange(epCliente);
}
```

caso queira apenas os clientes...

```
var clientes = db.EtapaProcess
    .Include(etapa => etapa.Cliente) // acredito que este include seja desnecessário.
    .GroupBy(etapa => etapa.Cliente)
    .Where(grupo => grupo
        .OrderByDescending(etapa => etapa.ID)
        .Select(etapa => etapa.EP)
        .FirstOfDefault() == 2)
    .Select(grupo => grupo.Key);
```

**ATUALIZAÇÂO**

Acredito que você não precisa fazer uma ligação com a tabela de clientes para obter o resultado esperado, você pode usar uma consultar como abaixo:

```
DECLARE @ep AS INT;
SET @ep = 2;

WITH CTE_Processos AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClienteID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Ordem,
        ClienteID,
        EP
    FROM estagioprocesso
)

SELECT ClienteID FROM CTE_Processos WHERE Ordem = 1 AND EP = @ep;
```

Neste caso, faça o seguinte:

```
var clientes = db.EtapaProcess
    .GroupBy(etapa => etapa.ClienteID)
    .Where(grupo => grupo
        .OrderByDescending(etapa => etapa.ID)
        .Select(etapa => etapa.EP)
        .FirstOfDefault() == id)
    .Select(grupo => grupo.Key);
```

Comment: for ou foreach ?

Comment: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead. esse erro apareceu pra mim

Comment: desculpa, realmente é o `foreach`, quando ao erro, substitua o `First` pelo `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: agora rodou, mas trouxe 11 resultados nada haver..mas acho que é bem por ai, com o groupby

Comment: @Dorathoto, realmente não entendi que dados você precisa, inicialmente pensei que precisava todo o histórico de etapas dos clientes que estão em uma determinada etapa, depois deu a entender que apenas os clientes já seria suficiente.

Comment: Funcionou, na verdade o meu é como se fosse um inner join só traz o campo onde em ambos tem resultado o seu como se fosse um left join traz os etapaProcess mesmo que não tenha no cliente.. preciso só corrigir isso e boa...

Comment: @Dorathoto, da uma olhada na atualização da minha resposta, teste tanto a consulta (sql), quanto o linq.

Answer (score 3):

Está bem errada sua consulta. Pelo que eu entendi dela, faça o seguinte:

```
var EP = db.EtapaProcess
   .Include(t => t.Cliente)
   .Where(x => x.EP == ep) // ep é uma variável que viria de algum lugar.
   .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
   .GroupBy(t => t.ClienteId);
```

Comment: Só trocou o Order by né?

Comment: A ordem dos métodos de extensão afeta a consulta gerada como um todo.

Comment: Faz tanto tempo que nao uso Linq que nem lembrava... obrigado mestre

Comment: mas esse .Take(1) não traria apenas um resultado? eu quero todos os clientes onde a última EtapaProcesso esteja no ID especificado.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.