# Subconsulta em Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, expressões-lambda

Gostaria de fazer uma subconsulta, hoje no SQL:

```
SELECT        intid as IDCliente,
                             (SELECT        TOP (1) int_EP
                               FROM            tbl_estagioprocesso
                               WHERE        (int_IDC = tbl_Admin.intid)
                               ORDER BY int_ID DESC) AS int_EP
FROM            tbl_Admin WITH (nolock)
WHERE        ((SELECT        TOP (1) int_EP
                            FROM            tbl_estagioprocesso AS tbl_estagioprocesso_1
                            WHERE        (int_IDC = tbl_Admin.intid)
                            ORDER BY int_ID DESC) = 4)
```

No caso faço um select na tabela clientes onde na tabela estagioprocesso o último int_EP seja=4 (ou a variável que desejar)

A consulta abaixo também retorna parecido (não fiz com consulta na tabela cliente)

```
DECLARE @ep AS INT;
SET @ep = 4;

WITH CTE_Processos AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [int_IDC] ORDER BY [int_ID] DESC) AS Ordem,
        [int_IDC],
        [int_EP]
    FROM tbl_estagioprocesso
)

SELECT [int_IDC] FROM CTE_Processos WHERE Ordem = 1 AND [int_EP] = @ep;
```

**Agora como fazer em Lambda ou Linq?**

**Minha Model:**

```
[Table("tbl_estagioprocesso")]
public class EstagioProcesso
{
    [Key]
    [Column("int_ID")]
    public int EpId { get; set; }

    [Column("int_IDC")]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Column("int_EP")]
    public byte EP { get; set; }

    [Column("sdt_Data")]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Column("int_IDFuncionario")]
    public int IdFuncionario { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
```

**Como tentei a consulta:**

```
var epClientes = db.EstagioProcess
                .Include(etapa => etapa.Cliente)
                .GroupBy(etapa => etapa.ClienteId)
                .Where(grupo => grupo
                    .OrderByDescending(etapa => etapa.EpId).Take(1)
                    .Select(etapa => etapa.EP)
                    .FirstOrDefault() == id);

            var EP = new List<EstagioProcesso>();
            foreach (var epCliente in epClientes)
            {
                EP.AddRange(epCliente);
            }
```

**Dados do meu SQL**

[image: Dados do meu SQL]

Onde:

```
int_ID (autonumeravel)
int_IDC (ClienteId)
int_EP (Id do Estagio do Processo)
```

Ou seja, deveria trazer apenas o registro int_ID=8718, pois o int_IDC (IdCliente) ele tem 3 registros mas o último EP está no 4.

**O que a consulta deve fazer:** Retornar o último estágio_processo do cliente, ou seja, o cliente pode ter vários, mas qual é o último `(TOP 1 ...order by ID DESC)`

Na minha consulta ele retorna os 3 registros.
[image: Com ID 4, ele retorna todos registros do cliente]
Com Id=4, ok ele encontra, porém traz todos registros (3) deveria só trazer a int_ID=8718

[image: Com Id=2 ele não encontra resultado (ok, esperado)]
Com Id=2 ele não encontra resultado, ok correto :)

Desculpe a pergunta ficar grande, mas quis mostrar todo o processo. 
Essa pergunta já é uma atualização da minha dúvida inicial:
[Lambda, Where com subconsulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111546/lambda-where-com-subconsulta/111561#111561)

Comment: Meu cliente pode passar pelo estágio de processo que vai de 1 a 10, com várias ordens, tipo vai pro 1, depois pro 7, volta pro 4, enfim, preciso identificar em qual Estagio ele está:

Comment: você já tentou fazer em dois passos, primeiro buscar o dados do tbl_estagioprocesso e depois da tbl_Admin ?

Comment: Não, teria como dar um exemplo básico?

Comment: você pode passa o design das suas tabelas.

Comment: já tentou experimentar a utilização de Sql Profile?

Comment: passe os seus arquivos Entity.cs relevantes.

Comment: coloquei o print do meu SQL e a minha model mostra os nomes dos campos do SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecionar a última (maior) etapa para cada cliente:

```
var query = from regAdmin in db.tbl_Admin
            select new {
                  Cliente = regAdmin,
                  EtapaAtual = (from regEtapa in db.tbl_estagioprocesso
                                where regEtapa.ClienteId == regAdmin.Id
                                orderby regEtapa.EP descending
                                select regEtapa.EP).FirstOrDefault()
            }
```

Selecionar somente clientes que estejam em uma etapa específica (a partir da variável contendo a query criada acima):

```
var clientesNaEtapaQuatro = (from clienteEtapa in query
                             where clienteEtapa.EtapaAtual == 4
                             select clienteEtapa.Cliente).ToList()
```

*Obs: As queries acima não equivalem ao SQL que você postou, mas deve te dar um norte. Como não possuía o schema para a entidade `tbl_Admin`, chutei o nome dos campos desta tabela.*

Comment: Pelo que entendi a primeira eu retorno todos os clientes e mais uma coluna chamada etapaAtual e na segunda verifico nesse resultado gerado qual está na etapa=4? retornou vazio...vou verificar o pq.

Comment: Isso mesmo. A ideia é essa. Verifique qual o SQL que ele está gerando - talvez tenha algum ajuste a mais a ser feito.

Comment: achei o erro: orderby regEtapa.EpId descending dai funcionou (ele tem que ordenar por esse campo que é o autonumeravel da tabela em ordem descendente..
Porém, todo esse processo não é trabalhoso demais? pesquisar nos meus 10mil clientes ? na tabela estagioprocess não chega nem a 2mil registros..
Vou fazer alguns testes, mas parece que é esse o caminho...

Comment: @Dorathoto: Perceba que, no meu exemplo, a query só será executada quando for chamado o método ToList() (segunda parte do código). Em outras palavras, os dois trechos formam uma query SQL só a ser enviada ao banco de dados. Não creio que seja uma grande dificuldade para o SQL Server processar isso - mas é caso de se avaliar.

Answer (score 1):

você pode fazer assim:

```
var processos = 
    from processo in db.EstagioProcess
    group new { 
        ClienteId = processo.ClienteId, 
        EpId = processo.EpId, 
        EP = processo.EP 
    } by processo.ClienteId into grupo
    select grupo.OrderByDescending(processo => processo.EpId).FirstOrDefault();

var clientes = 
    from processo in processos
    where processo.EP == 4
    select processo.ClienteId
```

Comment: Creio que o  where processo.EP = 4 seja com 2== ? vou testar e aviso

Comment: e no var clientes,.. seja var clientes =
                from processo in db.EstagioProcess?

Comment: até entendi a sua lógica, mas não deu certo...depois tentei um clientes.toList()   Message = "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."

Comment: @Dorathoto, realmente era "=="... porém no resto está certo.

Comment: @Dorathoto, fiz uma atualização